# BLDC motor electrical constant in Vms/krpm?

Tags: electrical-engineering, motors

At [this random motor shop](https://sdp-si.com/products/motors-gearheads-and-motion-control/frameless-brushless-dc-motors/Index.php) and elsewhere (in the results of
STMicroelectronics' motor profiler), I find a K<sub>e</sub> constant expressed in Vms/krpm.

If this were Vrms/krpm, I would guess that "rms" would stand for root mean square, and be happy with it, but I am at loss with "ms". Since V/krpm is an acceptable unit for a motor's electrical constant, I don't see how taking a mean square can lead to a valid electrical constant. I don't think interpreting "ms" as meter.second would make sense either.

So what am I looking at here?

Comment: It looks to me like as nothing more than a spelling mistake in a poorly maintained site --

Comment: So misspelt root mean square then?

Comment: This is just my opinion. Since it's blDC it shouldn't even read RMS to be honest.

Comment: *At this random motor shop* doesn't mean there are not typos!  Afterall you are the one calling it *random*.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat, yes I said *random*, and I also explicitly mentioned that STMicroelectronics' motor profiler used the same "unit" for Ke. That both would be wrong crossed my mind of course, but asking the experts before drawing any final conclusion felt reasonable enough...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The consensus seems to be that Vms/krpm is just a spelling mistake, and that the unit meant was Vrms/krpm, i.e. V/krpm for the root mean square voltage.

And for the sake of honesty, I have to mention that when starting ST's motor profiler one more time, I can now see Vrms/kRPM. It is just a little hard to distinguish because of the font and size they have picked:

[image]